# export solpg project locally but got error TS1378 running the client script due to top-level await

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I converted & exported this solpg project https://beta.solpg.io/658d772ecffcf4b13384ceb6 to local. Note the project runs all fine on solpg, including running `client`.

After running `anchor build` locally, I run `anchor run client` trying to run the client.ts code. However this is what I get:

```
/Users/0xbe1/solana-programs/transfer_tokens/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
client/client.ts(12,17): error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
```

Note this is my client.ts script

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import type { SolanaLamportTransfer } from "../target/types/solana_lamport_transfer";

// Configure the client to use the local cluster
anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

const program = anchor.workspace.SolanaLamportTransfer as anchor.Program<SolanaLamportTransfer>;

// Client
console.log("My address:", program.provider.publicKey.toString());
const balance = await program.provider.connection.getBalance(program.provider.publicKey);
console.log(`My balance: ${balance / web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} SOL`);
```

And here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["mocha", "chai"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Ideally it should run well as in solpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because solpg uses a different layout than Anchor framework, make sure you use the "Convert and export" option when exporting your project.

To fix your issue, you can wrap `client.ts` code in a `async` function:

```
(async () => {
   // Configure the client to use the local cluster
   anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
   const program = anchor.workspace.HelloAnchor as anchor.Program<HelloAnchor>;

   // Client
   console.log("My address:", program.provider.publicKey.toString());
   const balance = await program.provider.connection.getBalance(program.provider.publicKey);
   console.log(`My balance: ${balance / web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} SOL`);
})();
```

Note that `anchor run client` will by default run against a local cluster that you have to start manually with `anchor localnet`.

You can also change the cluster using the `--provider.cluster` argument:
`anchor run client --provider.cluster https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`.

Hope this helps!